# project run fail with Desugar

Tags: android, gradle, java-8

My android project fails on run with this error i searched all questions on so and according to answers i cleaned my project , rebuilt it , .... disable d8 and still getting error.
But the main question is why it not showing whats make this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForGreenDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/1.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/9.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/21.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/29.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/69.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/77.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/77.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/85.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/48.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/56.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/78.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/86.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/50.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/58.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/18.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/26.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/20.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/28.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/72.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/80.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/68.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/76.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/90.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/98.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/65.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/73.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/classes/green/debug --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/7 --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/60.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/68.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/34.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/42.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/40.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/48.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/3.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/11.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/66.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/74.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/28.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/36.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/27.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/35.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/5.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/13.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/shimmer-android/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/5.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/expandable-layout/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/2.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/75.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/83.jar --input /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/71.jar --output /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/green/debug/79.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/input-dialogs-library/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/MultiThreadDownload/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/expandable-layout/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/BGABanner/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/tab-controller/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/shimmer-android/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/ExoPlayerLibrary/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/classes/green/debug --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/2.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/3.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/4.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/5.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/6.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/7.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/8.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/9.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/10.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/11.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/12.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/13.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/14.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/15.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/16.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/17.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/18.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/19.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/20.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/21.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/22.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/23.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/24.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/25.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/26.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/27.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/28.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/29.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/30.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/31.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/32.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/33.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/34.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/35.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/36.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/37.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/38.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/39.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/40.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/41.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/42.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/43.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/44.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/45.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/46.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/47.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/48.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/49.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/50.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/51.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/52.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/53.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/54.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/55.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/56.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/57.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/58.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/59.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/60.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/61.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/62.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/63.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/64.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/65.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/66.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/67.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/68.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/69.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/70.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/71.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/72.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/73.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/74.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/75.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/76.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/77.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/78.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/79.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/80.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/81.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/82.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/83.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/84.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/85.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/86.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/87.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/88.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/89.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/90.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/91.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/92.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/93.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/94.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/95.jar --classpath_entry /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject/myAndroidProjectApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/green/debug/96.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/babak/Documents/androidDevelopment/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-26/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/babak/Documents/androidDevelopment/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-26/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar --min_sdk_version 16 --desugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}

Answer (score 0):

Guess it has to do with Windows command-line string limitation - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation

One solution would be to use something shorther than /Users/babak/Desktop/Projects/myAndroidProject for your root

Answer (score 0):

in gradle.properties add the following:

```
android.enableD8.desugaring = true
```